Dynamic ChoiceType Field Loses Value on Form Submission in Symfony 6
I have 2 fields which accept string:
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private ?string $pattern = null;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'sub_pattern', type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private ?string $subPattern = null;

My form :
->add('pattern', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'contact.form.pattern.title',
                'choices' => PatternEnum::getChoicesToString(),
                'required' => true,
            ])
            ->add('subPattern', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'contact.form.sub_pattern.title',
                'required' => true,
            ])

PatternEnum::getChoicesToString() return an array where key and value are key translation :
public static function getChoicesToString(): array
    {
        return array_combine(
            array_map(fn ($case) => $case->value, self::cases()),
            array_map(fn ($case) => $case->value, self::cases())
        );
    }

When I select an option from pattern, the value from subPattern change. I use Javascript and this is my Controller :
public function fetchSubMotifsByMotif(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator): JsonResponse
    {
        $jsonPattern = $request->getContent();
        $pattern = json_decode($jsonPattern, true);

        if (!$pattern) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'Le motif est obligatoire'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        try {
            $subPatterns = match ($pattern['patternValue']) {
                PatternEnum::AFTER_SALES_SERVICE->value => SubPatternEnum::getByAfterSalesService(),
                PatternEnum::DELIVERY_INFORMATION->value => SubPatternEnum::getByDepositInformation(),
                PatternEnum::PRODUCT->value => SubPatternEnum::getByAvailableProduct(),
                PatternEnum::ORDER_TRACKING->value => SubPatternEnum::getByOrderTracking(),
                PatternEnum::OTHER_REQUESTS->value => SubPatternEnum::getByOtherRequests(),
                PatternEnum::TECHNICAL_PROBLEMS->value => SubPatternEnum::getByTechnicalProblems(),
                default => throw new \InvalidArgumentException(\sprintf('Valeur inconnue: %s',$pattern)),
            };
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => $e->getMessage()], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        $formattedSubPatterns = [];
        foreach ($subPatterns as $key => $value) {
            $formattedSubPatterns[] = [
                'value' => $value,
                'label' => $translator->trans($value)
            ];
        }
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => [
                'subPatterns' => $formattedSubPatterns
            ],
        ]);
    }

In the DOM every option has the correct value, the ajax works well but When I submit the value subPattern become null, I don't know how and why because in PRE_SUBMIT the value is the correct string (for example: contact.form.pattern.after_sales_service).
